# How incremental indexing happens for a new data in datasource?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

blob storage have blobs like `new/1.json`, `new/2.json`

I have a index called `new-index`, indexer called `new-indexer` and datasource called `new-datasource`
my datasouce body is like this:

```
{
    "name" : "new-datasource",
    "type" : "azureblob",
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "MyStorageConnStrning" },
    "container" : { "name" : "mycontaner", "query" : "new" }
}
```

`"query" : "new"` means while running the indexer it will take all the blobs from Virtual Directory `new` from blob storage.

Indexer run has a start time and an end time. And I know that indexer does incremental indexing based on `lastModified` property of the blob([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-reindex#partial-or-incremental-indexing)).

Question is, between the start time and the end time of indexer run if a new blob is created like `new/3.json` in Virtual Directory `new`, will this blob also get indexed by this indexer run or does another run needs to occur for it to get indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question is, between the start time and the end time of indexer run if
>   a new blob is created like new/3.json in Virtual Directory new, will
>   this blob also get indexed by this indexer run or does another run
>   needs to occur for it to get indexed.

The answer is a little more involved than what Joey said. Since the indexer indexes the blobs by enumerating them in pages, a new blob even with an updated timestamp may or may not be picked up by the indexer depending upon the page it gets placed in.

The only guarantees the indexer provides are -

- Indexer will index all blobs with a **LastModified timestamp before indexer start time** for sure in the same run.
- Incremental changes will **eventually** be indexed because of data change detection policy. This means they may or may not be indexed in the same run.

It's not advisable to make any assumptions past the high watermark and when the new blob gets indexed is technically undefined behavior.

Checkout this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage) for more details. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> will this blob also get indexed by this indexer run or does another run needs to occur for it to get indexed.

In short, **yes**. It will get indexed by this indexer because of [dataChangeDetectionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#data-change-detection-policies).

When using Azure Blob data sources, Azure Search **automatically uses a high watermark change detection policy** based on a blob's `last-modified` timestamp. With [high watermark](https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/azure/search/search-howto-reindex#partial-indexing-with-indexers), you can use it for incremental change detection by picking up just those rows containing **new or revised content**.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/blog/azure-search-indexer-for-azure-blob-storage-now-in-public-preview/).